# Meteor JS meteor pages showing all records on new account create

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have found bug in my application. I believe that it's problem with meteor-pages pagination or with some data being cached. I'm also using stardard accounts package for logging and signing up.

The problem is that if I have two tabs opened in my browser, and on one of them I log out, create a new account and immediately log out from that new account, then when I change to that second browser tab, and log in on my normal account and switch to one of views I can see all items of BrandCampaignsPagination pagination, which shouldn't happen, instead I should only be able to see my personal campaigns.

Everything goes back to normal when I reload my browser tab.

Below you can see my pagination:

```
  @BrandCampaignsPagination = new Meteor.Pagination Campaigns,
    availableSettings:
      filters: true
      sort: true
    perPage: 10
    templateName: 'campaignPaginate'
    itemTemplate: 'singleCampaign'
    navShowFirst: false
    navShowLast: false
    maxSubscriptions: 100
    divWrapper: false
```

And also controller:

```
class Brands.CampaignsController extends Brands.BaseController
  action: ->
    @render "brandsCampaigns#{@params.status.capitalize()}"

  waitOn: ->
    Meteor.subscribe 'brandCampaignsProposals', @params.status
    Meteor.subscribe 'money-package-fxrates'

  onStop: ->
    BrandCampaignsPagination.unsubscribe()

  onRerun: ->
    BrandCampaignsPagination.unsubscribe()
    @next()

  onBeforeAction: ->
    BrandCampaignsPagination.set
      filters:
        userId: Meteor.userId()
        status: @params.status
    @next()
```

I even tried onStop and onRerun hooks to force unsubscription on pagination collection but it didn't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I have solution, the problem was with pagination and lack of authentication function, with the extension for pagination posted below everything works like a charm.

```
@BrandCampaignsPagination = new Meteor.Pagination Campaigns,
    availableSettings:
      filters: true
      sort: true
    perPage: 10
    templateName: 'campaignPaginate'
    itemTemplate: 'singleCampaign'
    navShowFirst: false
    navShowLast: false
    maxSubscriptions: 100
    divWrapper: false
    auth: (skip,subscription) ->
      alwaysFilters =
        userId: subscription.userId

      userPagination = BrandCampaignsPagination.userSettings[subscription._session.id] || {}
      userFilters = userPagination.filters || {}
      userSort = userPagination.sort || {}

      unless _.contains _.values(CampaignStatuses), userFilters.status
        userFilters.status = CampaignStatuses.PUBLISHED

      filters = _.extend alwaysFilters,
        status: userFilters.status

      options =
        sort: userSort,
        skip: skip,
        limit: @perPage

      [filters,options]
```